# Why should we 'get a stable reference' in Kotlin/Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camerax

I was reading Android CameraX codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#4

The simplified code snippet is like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    
    //(some other codes here...)

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return
        
        //(some other codes here...)

    }
}
```

In the codelab, it says:

> First, get a reference to the ImageCapture use case.

Why do we need a new reference `imageCapture` in `takePhoto()`?

Can't we just use the `imageCapture` in `MainActivity`?

Is this for some kind of 'best practice' stuff or am I missing something?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you think happens if some other code in another thread modifies `imageCapture` in the middle of `takePhoto`?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I think it's just a referencing, not copying, so the modified `imageCapture` would be used in the `takePhoto`, even in the original codelab code, isn't it?

Comment: In the _middle_ of takePhoto -- so if takePhoto didn't take the snapshot, the variable could be changed out in the middle of the function, which could cause chaos.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You must be right, but I really don't get it... When you said 'snapshot', does it mean 'copying' the `imageCapture`? If the `imageCapture` is copied at the beginning of the `takePhoto` method, then your comment makes sense. but I think it's not copy, it's just a reference to an object.. Sorry if I misunderstood something. Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: It's copying the reference.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh, what you're saying is, taking a snapshot(clone) of the 'reference', not the object itself? Alright I gotcha. So when you said *"...if some other code in another thread 'modifies' `imageCapture`..."*, the 'modifies' means assigning a different object, not modifying the original object itself. Did I understand correctly? So, if the original object itself is modified(not re-assigned) in a different thread, then it would cause chaos anyway, unless we deep copy the object itself. Please let me know if I understood incorrectly. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think ADM commented the same thing that I mentioned, in the comment of the answer below - *"Even though the variable changes in middle a shallow copy will also get changed. So that's why they are all same . only After cloning we can make sure that local reference does not get effected from the actual one."*

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If you're properly using immutable objects, then that copy of the reference is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its equivalent to a null check .

```
stable reference -> Not null reference
```

its similar to

```
if(imageCapture==null) return;
```

Also in the code lab they have mentioned the same thing.

> First, get a reference to the ImageCapture use case. If the use case is null, exit out of the function. This will be null If you tap the photo button before image capture is set up. Without the return statement, the app would crash if it was null.

So basically you are removing the possibility of an NPE which can done in multiple ways and they happen to use a Another local variable for it . it can also be done with `let`.

```
imageCapture?.let{
 // code goes here
   }
```

Comment: *"...which can done in multiple ways and they happen to use a Another local variable for it..."* So it's just one of the many ways to avoid NPE, right? Thanks a lot! Now I got it.

Comment: Its not equivalent, `if(imageCapture==null) return;` will still not help, if the variable changed in the middle you'll still get weird things happen, and compiler won't allow non-null `.` calls on the object even with this check in the same regards. `?.let` will do a shallow copy, same as the snippet in the question which will be safe from changes from outside.

Comment: Even though the variable changes in middle a shallow copy will also get changed. So that's why they are all same . only After cloning we can make sure that local reference does not get effected from the actual one.

Answer (score 1):

```
private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
```

With this line you are assigning null on imageCapture variable. Now, when you start using takePhoto() how will the compiler know that imageCapture is not null anymore?

As @ADM describes, you can use

```
imageCapture?.let{
  //your code goes here
}
```

if you want. This is basically making sure you don't call anything on a nullable object.